# How to change URL in a chromium tab from a script

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have an open browser on a certain web page. Is it possible to visit a new URL in that browser (same tab) by executing a command from the terminal or a python script?

Answer (score 1):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get("firefox").open("http://www.python.org")
webbrowser.open("http://www.python.org")
```

Comment: You can use the python standard library `webbrowser` from the command line as well. `python -m webbrowser -t "http://www.python.org"`

Comment: This opens a new tab. I want to change the url in the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same kind of concern for kiosk mode using raspberry pi.

I took another approach with a node/express local http server that serve a single html page embedding a dynamic iframe.

Changing the source of the i frame is done when a web socket message is received.

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script type = "text/javascript">
      if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
          try {
            dataObj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            if (dataObj.actionType === "displayPage") {
              alert(dataObj.actionParam);
              document.getElementById("iframeTarget").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + dataObj.actionParam;
            }
          }
          catch (err) {
            alert(err)
          }
        };
        ws.onclose = function() {
          alert("Connection is closed...");
        };
      } else {
        alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
      }
  </script>

  <style>
    body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
    .second-row iframe {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;}
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NHZL4MG4F90" id="iframeTarget" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
  Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
</body>
</html
```